# Testing StreamController with one listener present

Tags: dart, unit-testing, dart-test

I wanted to know how are `StreamController` with listener assigned or implemented are tested.

I have a class as follows:

```dart
class Foo<T>{
  
  late final StreamController<T> _streamController;
  
  Foo(){
    _streamController = StreamController<T>();
    _streamController.stream.listen((T data)=> _aListner); // listner attached to the stream.

  }
  
  void _aListner(T data){
    // doing something with the data
    print(data);
  }
  
  void addData(T data){
    _streamController.add(data);
  }
  
  Stream<T> get stream => _streamController.stream;
  
}
```

I want to implement an test to check if data is added to the stream in order (a simple test using the Stream matcher). But it always throws an error that the stream has already been listened to.

test implementation:

```dart
test('stream getter  test.', ()async {
  
      final Foo<String> foo = Foo<String>();  
      const String data1 = 'data1';
      const String data2 = 'data2';
      const String data3 = 'data3';
      const String data4 = 'data4';


      foo.addData(data1);
      foo.addData(data2);
      foo.addData(data3);
      foo.addData(data4);


      print(foo.stream.length); // even this throws- Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
    });
```

I know converting the `_streamController` to broadcast would resolve the issue. But the defined class has only one listener function and this is by design, so no need of making it broadcast stream.

I can Mock the class using `mockito`, but the constructor mocking is not supported ( I may be wrong here please correct me, if so).

The main objective here is used to `StreamMatcher` in test cases and use `emitsInOrder` or `emits`, [read here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-matcher_expect/StreamMatcher-class.html).

Answer (score -1):

Stream.length is adding a new listener, because it will listen to the stream and try to count the number of events. You are listening twice now.

You can add a property foo.length and change the method _aListner to

```
void _aListner(T data){
  // doing something with the data
  print(data);
  length++;
}
```

Now you can test foo.length instead of foo.stream.length.

Comment: Thank you @rene this won't suffice, since the if I need to use StreamMatcher in my tests that's the objective here... Maybe I will modify the question indicating this.

Comment: Do you also really need to have the _aListner in Foo? Because your issue is that you add 2 listeners. If you want to add a listener to the stream in the test, you can't also add it in the Foo class.

Comment: Yes, I need to have a listener in Foo, that does some processing on the streamdata

Comment: Sounds like you really want to add 2 listeners without making it a broadcaststream. That's just impossible. You should test the stream outside of Foo and perhaps mock the stream when you test Foo so you have isolated unit tests